# for loop inside a for loop with if else condition

Tags: c, nested-loops

```
for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    for (int a = 22; a <= 62;) {
        if (isCooked[x] == 1) {
            gotoxy(a,3); printf("cooked");
            gotoxy(a,4); printf("%-10s",food[userServings[x]]);
            a += 12;
        } else {
            gotoxy(a,3); printf("!");
            gotoxy(a,4); printf("%-10s",food[userServings[x]]);
            a += 12;
        }
    }
}
```

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srN2h.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw9hb.png)

May I ask whats wrong with loop above and conditions. I'm trying to print the name of the 4 vegetables that I have chosen. By using `gotoxy` I want to print them on the given coordinates on my loop.

Comment: And what happens when you run the code you show? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: i uploaded the input and the output.

Comment: It's still not clear what problem you have with the code you show. You show the output from the program, but is that the *actual* or the *expected* output? If it's the actual output, what is the expected output? If it's the expected, then what is the actual output?

Comment: the problem of my program was already answered. thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do people insist on uploading *pictures* of *text*?? Just copy and paste it here. Pictures do not help future visitors as they may dissapear from the the web and it doesn't help us because we can't copy and paste it to try to run it and help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a second loop, you should just compute the `gotoxy` coordinate:

```
for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    int a = 22 + x * 12;

    if (isCooked[x] == 1) {
        gotoxy(a, 3); printf("cooked");
        gotoxy(a, 4); printf("%-10s", food[userServings[x]]);
    } else {
        gotoxy(a, 3); printf("!     ");
        gotoxy(a, 4); printf("%-10s", food[userServings[x]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked on my program.

Answer (score 1):

In c you can't declare variable anywhere. You have declared int a in the inner for loop.

Comment: It depends on what version of C the compiler is using.

Comment: Just try this code . If it is working in your c compiler let me know which compiler your using. and please save this code using .c extension.                

#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
 int i;
 
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  for(int j=1;j<3;j++){
   printf("%d",j);
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

in your program x is not declared